# Finding a typographical error in a large .bib file

Tags: bibtex, errors, tufte

*I cannot provide a minimum-working example because of the large sizes of all files, as you'll see.*

I'm writing a very large book (tufte-book under TeXShop 3.0), with nine included chapters and an Appendix, containing many hundreds of citations.  The text typesets appropriately, but when I run BibTeX I get the following report in my console:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2018)
The top-level auxiliary file: PaP.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: PaPCh1.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: PaPCh2.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: PaPCh3.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: PaPCh4.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: PaPCh5.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: PaPCh6.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: PaPCh7.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: PaPCh8.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: PaPCh9.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: PaPApp.aux
The style file: plainnat.bst
Database file #1: Art.bib
Your field is more than 20000 characters---line 1543 of file Art.bib
 :          YEAR = "
 :                  2005"
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "CriminisiKempZisserman:05"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "CriminisiStork:04"
```

and many other similar "Warning" entries following.

The errant line (line 1543) in the Art.bib file is the last line in this entry:

```
@ARTICLE{Fiorentini:05,
       EDITOR = "Erna Fiorentini",
        TITLE = "Drawing with optical instruments.  {D}evices and Concepts of Visuality and Representation",
        JOURNAL = "{ECHO} Open Digital Library",
      ADDRESS = "{\tt echo.mpiwg-berlin.mpg.de/content/optics}",
         YEAR = "2005"
}
```

As far as I can see, the entry is properly formatted.  I've even retyped it to check.  Given the warning in the console report "Your field is more than 20000 characters" it seems that the error must lie far earlier in the Art.bib file (perhaps an unmatched double quotation mark or curly bracket?).  But is this truly the source of the BibTeX error?  And how can I find (and of course *fix*) this error?

My Art.bib has entries listed alphabetically by key, and I *DO* have a list of properly cited entries.  So I'm guessing my error must come (shortly?) after the last properly-typeset entry.

Comment: (1) You could test the supposedly faulty entry on a very simple document calling that reference to see whether the problem persists. (2) the ADDRESS field is not supposed to store a URL link I believe

Comment: what is 2000 characters earlier in that file?  Otherwise use divide and conquer: split the bib file in two (and include both bib files in your document) keep doing that splitting the file with the error until you find it.

Comment: Can we see the bib file?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Sebastiano - user also of Math.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, 20th century error-handling is not always what we might like. What I've found to be useful in these sorts of situations is to start deleting big chunks of the .bib file to narrow it down. I'd start by deleting every entry starting around line 500 and see if the error persists. If it does, then keep deleting backwards using a binary search algorithm (e.g., try deleting everything after line ~250, ~125, ~60, etc.), if it doesn't then the error is in what remains so start adding in about half of what you deleted and use binary search logic to narrow it down.

My guess is that it's probably a missing }.

Comment: Oh gosh... I thought of that approach but *really* hoped I didn't have to go through such a laborious method.  Is there some way to put in a *break* in Art.bib so I can "eliminate" following entries and thus speed my search?

Comment: If your editor supports it, you could go back 20,000 characters from that line of your .bib file. In Emacs, esc-20000-C-b should do the trick.

Comment: Alas, my Mac editor doesn't have the ability to search back a specific number of characters, but I guess I'll just have to port Art.bib to MS Word or other word-processing program that has this ability...

Comment: If you have a pre-Catalina OS X, there should be a command line emacs available to you.

Comment: Well... I did a thorough search (using MS Word) to 20,000 characters before the flagged line (first by raw character, and then by character with blank spaces) and came to entries that look perfect.  What should I do *now*??

Comment: I think you're going to have to start deleting stuff then. I'm guessing the problem might be earlier than the naive count would reveal since I think (it's been a long time since I've looked at bibtex.web) that bibtex might not count leading spaces at the beginning of the line in its character count.

Comment: What about using a tool like Bibdesk or Jabref . Often they can identify syntactic errors in bibtex files.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this has already been answered, using the tried-and-true "divide and conquer" method, I've just remembered an approach that can assist by speeding up the search.

Using an editor that has the ability to count instances of a particular character (I use emacs), start at the very beginning and ask for two reports:

- How many `{`
- How many `}`

If there are no errors, the answers should be the same value; in other words, there are exactly the same number of opening and closing braces so that everything is properly scoped.  If these values don't match, you know that is the problem; now you need to find out where.

Next, go to the point where the alleged error was reported, and back up a reasonable distance to a point between complete entries.  Ask "how many" again.  If the values are the same, the problem is earlier; if not, the problem is later.

Continue moving backward or forward in the file as necessary.  It's still divide and conquer, but is faster than rerunning BibTeX.

Comment: barbarabeeton:  I had wanted to try the counting approach immediately, but didn't see how to do such a count with my Mac editor.

Answer (score 0):

I followed (in essence) the advice of @DonaldHosek and did a divide and conquer search through the Art.bib file and found the errant missing `}` (which was instead a `"`).  What a pain!  There should be a efficient way to typeset a whole .bib file where (I guess) an error would be easier to catch.

Regardless, many thanks to Donald!

Comment: Tools like `bibdesk` and `jabref` check the correctness of bibtex entries in a `.bib` files. Also, creating bibtex databases with such tools prevent errors like the one reported in the OP.

Comment: Pro-Tip: Never use `"`, but always `{}`, because the latter nest. Much less error-prone.

Comment: `jabref` helped me to identify which citation was wrong when importing because it didn't show the wrong one in the list.